# What are the rules for importing personal items when relocating from Nepal to India?

Tags: india, customs, nepal

I will be moving to Nepal from India (Bangalore ) along with household stuff including few old electronics items ( Like 42 inch LCD TV , 2 sets of fans ).

Could someone please elaborate the process of passing all the items through the saunali border (Uttar pardesh) ?

Basically I would like to know if I can carry all the mentioned items using truck through the border . What would be the tax levied on the items and where I should be careful while moving it.